# Where is the gradle process on Windows task manager?

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

With `gradle --status` I can see the gradle PID, which is for example:

```
   PID STATUS   INFO
 12868 IDLE     7.4.1
```

Yet, on Windows Task Manager there is no process with PID 12868. I cannot find either any process with gradle on name.

Where is the gradle process on Windows task manager?

---

### Updated with @cisco information

For some unknown reason my Windows Task Manager is not updating with new processes after gradle daemon Java Process has started. I need to close and reopen Task Manager to see the corresponding Java process.

Next, you have the Print screens of Task Manager sorted by PID before and after closed and reopen.

[image: Task Manager sorted by PID not updating with new Gradle Java process]

[image: Task Manager sorted by PID after close and reopen showing the Gradle Java process]

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is a Java application, so the name of the process will have Java in it somewhere.

Given the PID, in Windows Task Manager, navigate to the Details tab. From there you can sort by PID or name to find the process.

For example, in the below screenshot, you can see the process ID of 8964 in PowerShell and the same process highlighted in the Details tab on the right in Windows Task Manager.

[image: sample]

Comment: For some unknown reason my  Windows Task Manager is not updating with new processes after gradle daemon Java Process has started. I need to close and reopen Task Manager to see the corresponding Java process. Updated OP  with print-screens showing that behavior.

Comment: Miguel, confirm that your task mgr. is not PAUSED.  consider pressing the space bar to toggle b/tw pause and not paused.